# Objective-c Base64 NSString to NSData conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, nsdata

I am trying to load in a very large string that is a base64 encoded PNG into `NSData` to create a `UIImage` on the fly.  I can get the image generated by it is very distorted.  Am I doing this correctly?  I am also using [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) in this example.

```
// Data is the NSData loaded in from the web
NSString *responseValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *successData = [(NSDictionary*)[responseValue JSONValue] objectForKey:@"MapFlightResult"];
NSData *pngData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:successData options:1];
UIImage *map = [UIImage imageWithData:mapData];
[imageView setImage:map];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you issue is that your not sending in a base64 encoded string to `initWithBase64EncodedString`.

Comment: How is that method preferable to using the built-in `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` method?

Comment: Did you try what I posted?

Comment: No, I assumed that you might have a reason for posting the code, and I wondered what it is.

Comment: What you have isn't working, so it's just a different approach. I've had `initWithBase64EncodedString:options` do weird things in the past as well.

Comment: Please note, I am not the person who asked this question. What purpose is your code intended to serve, and in what way is it a better choice than the built in method? How does it fix the "weird things" you have seen in the past?

Comment: The built in method is not working for him since he asked the question. My code is intended as an alternative for him to try. Off the top of my head I don't remember why I needed to roll my own method over the built in one. Do you have any suggestions for the OP?

Comment: No, I just thought that if you're posting a long method that appears to duplicate built-in functionality, you should to explain how your approach is different, why it's better, or what problem(s) it is intended to solve.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington I appreciate your input.

Comment: Your example did not work for me, but I did figure out what the issue was based upon your text response.  I was not sending the function a base64 encoded string.  Thank you.  What is the etiquette for marking the correct answer?  Should I mark your answer as accepted even though your code example did not work?

Comment: @AgnosticDev I will update it to reflect the correct answer, then you can accept it! Glad you were able to get it working

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you very much for your help.  I accepted the answer.